# Use a component inside another component same module not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular

My shared.module is:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
  ],
  exports: [
    Component1,
    Component2,
  ],
})
```

And i want to use Component2 inside Component1 but i have this error:
"'Component2' is not a known element".

Why is component2 not recognized by component1? Both are in the same module and the same level.

I'm using this shared.module in my HomePage. The Home.module is:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HomeRouterModule, SharedComponentsModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
})
```

Comment: where are you using it?

Comment: In my home page. The home module is:
@NgModule({
  imports: [HomeRouterModule, SharedComponentsModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
})

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and its working fine. Check here - https://codesandbox.io/s/wyrz49l5lw

Comment: Yes, finally it's correct, i had a problem with organization of other modules. Thanks!